# Cassandra: using a one letter as a shard key to reduce load to cluster

Tags: cassandra

I need to implement a functionality to search users by their nickname.

I know that it's possible to create a SASI index on a nickname and the search will work. However, as far as I understand the query will be sent to all nodes in the cluster.

I want to modify a table and introduce a shard key which will be first letter of the nickname. Like that if user starts to search, we know that we need to forward the query only to specific node ( + replicas ).

P.S I know that such kind of pattern can create a hotspot. However, I think the trade-offs here are meaningful and in practice I should not get an issue due to this hotspot ( I don't expect to get billion users in my system ).

What do you think?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you expect to search on full nickname only or by a substring within it, a-la `LIKE '%hello%'`?

Comment: No, only LIKE 'hello%'